# Overpass QL for Polygons of Land between streets

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I am trying to create a Overpass Query that would give me polygons of Land that is NOT a highway/street/waterbody/(anything place that cannot be residential).
The area Im looking does not have much mapping data. I wanted to have all residential areas and buildings but they arent mapped yet.

I need an alternative that would be a good guestimate of where these residential areas might be. (Not roads/waterbodies/parks)

I just can't seem to polygons of the spaces between the streets in the picture below.

#### UPDATE

Link to Overpass Link http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/j3I
This will fetch the roads and water bodies, I don't want the land, I just want the spaces between those roads

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query will return any ways with tags, that are not in the list of tags you wanted to be excluded:

```
[out:json];

(way[~"."~"."]({{bbox}}); - 
(

  way["natural"="water"]({{bbox}});
  way["natural"="water"]({{bbox}});
  way["water"="lake"]({{bbox}});
  way["natural"="coastline"]({{bbox}});
  way["waterway"="riverbank"]({{bbox}});

way["highway"~"primary|secondary|tertiary|residential|unclassified|service"]["sidewalk"!~"."]({{bbox}});

););


out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/j3P

Comment: is there no way to get that data by exclusion or something? there seem to be shapes there. I mean, surely theres something mapped, just not named.

Comment: Does the revised query answer your question?

Comment: aah, that again gets the roads. I wanted things linke landuse that are not roads/streets

Comment: I am getting the Buildings only.

Comment: No, roads are excluded, if they are primary/secondary/etc. If you want landuse, why don't you simply query for landuse? Overall, your question is very unclear. Can you please revise your question and formulate _pricely_ what you want? Again the reminder, **if the data is not in the OSM database, the query can never return such data!**

Comment: My apologies, I'm just not familiar with the GIS lingo. Please check this link: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/jgD , This will bring up "some" buildings and Location Polygons that are Tagged. I just wanted every space between the roads. I was assuming, that since the roads visually seen, there must be a query that creates polygons that reflect those blocks between the roads that are *not* tagged

Comment: No that's not possible with overpass turbo. You can only query the objects, which are shown in blue: http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=18/19.67472/78.53271&layers=D - spaces between roads are no object as such, hence you cannot query them.